# Сервер не отвечает на запросы некоторых пользователей

Tags: php, mysql, apache, сервер, ip

Есть мобильное приложение, которое при открытии обращается к серверу для загрузки данных об игроке. У небольшой части пользователей нет ответа от сервера, соответсвенно игра не запускается (на постоянной основе, вне зависимости от нагрузки на сервер, времени суток и тд). Какой-то систематичности не обнаружено - разные телефоны/регионы/ip. Запрос к серверу идёт через php-скрипт (открытие базы + взятие данных). ДНС от Cloudflare, если это важно.
Сам сервер - это выделенный сервер на windows с apache 2.4, БД MySQL. В логах apache ничего необычного не замечено.
IP сервера вряд ли заблокирован у кого-то из пользователей, так как недавно меняли сервер и IP сменился, а проблема осталась.
Уже всю голову сломали, в чём может быть причина. У кого-то есть идеи? В какую сторону копать?

Comment: У вас случайно не https с сертификатом lets encrypt ?

Comment: У нас на clouflare стоит настройка flexible - она позволяет шифровать траффик со стороны cloudflare через их SSL, свой SSL на сайт нам поставить не удалось сразу и мы не возвращались к этому вопросу. Сертификат на нашем сайте отображается от lets encrypt.

Comment: У lets encrypt несколько месяцев назад закончился корневой сертификат. Они то его поменяли, но вот некоторые андроиды вообще не обновляются (обычно китайские поделки) и ничего не знают о новом сертификате. в итоге ssl сессия просто не устанавливается

Comment: То есть установка своего SSL сертификата, отличного от текущего, на сервер должна помочь в такой ситуации?

Comment: Да. главное что бы в тех старых андроидах сертификат выбранного поставщика был. Теоретически любой поставщик сертификатов на таких андроидах со временем перестанет работать

Comment: Спасибо, Mike. Попробуем этот вариант.